# Is it possible to render a part of a website, using vanilla JavaScript instead of react.js?

Tags: javascript, express, rendering

I am learning web development, and I found that to render a change in a web-site, we will have to make a request to the server (say it's built using express.js), and the server will render the new page, from the EJS templates provided. But in this case, whenever a change has to be reflected on the client-side, the entire web-page must be received and rendered in the browser.

I want to know if there is a way in the vanilla JS, through which I can render only a part of the page, instead of rendering the complete page again and again?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can use plain Javascript in the browser, fetch data from the server and update the web page yourself using your Javascript.  You will have to create or modify DOM elements in the web page to show the updates or new content.

Comment: You can also use client-side templates to build new HTML loaded with new data that you then insert into the current web page.  This saves some of the drudgery of creating all the appropriate HTML yourself and lets the template engine do the detail work.  Templates also make the html content format easier to maintain because the HTML/CSS format is specified in the template rather than in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check this video. It's an ecommerce tutorial using javascript only in a ...react-kinda-way. The same guy has another one where he builds the exact same project but with React. So you can compare both methods.

Basic structure is

```
const layoutComponent = {
render: async () => {
...function content
}
return `
<div> things </div>
and html stuff
`
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3FDyheHVMM&t=8349s